# How can I leverage my experience organizing a large group in an Online Game?

Tags: resume

I'm in the midst of writing a CV, and I know for a fact that I have experience in organizing groups and planning activities (both informative/educational and recreational).

I know this due to playing a for a few years on a GTA:SA Roleplaying Server, where my character had to interact with other characters as a police instructor. Despite being a game, parts of my 'gameplay' were actually building an infrastructure and organizing/teaching new recruits for our medium sized server. On a good day I was tasked with organizing between 20-30 individuals (over the internet, in a game - and yes with some disruptive participants), however, on some rare occasions I had to handle almost 60 people at once.

In a way, it did provide me with experience in organizing real people, albeit being in a virtual context, however I'm not so sure if this would be frowned upon. How should I handle this "experience" ?

Comment: While it could be useful in the way fast-paced games improve real hand-eye coordination, I doubt anyone will ever take such seriously in the real world.

Comment: But wouldn't the same be applied for management/organization skills, in other lines of work?

Comment: @oak No, gameing experience is different from Company. Gamers are more cooperative in most roleplaying Servers. Makeing it often more easyer also you dont have to Argument with Player x why has to do y. Any real worker/Manager wants hard numbers not the Default because we do

Comment: Adding on it you don't have a ban/mute button

Comment: @RaoulMensink Either I have played with more needy gamers or my corporate life has been perfect so far... in my experience, gamers are *way* harder to manage, because they don't have anything to lose. And "because I pay you" is not a valid reason either. Getting 40-50 people organized that actually have other priorities (including their job) and only follow you if and when they like and respect you is *way* harder then being a bad corporate leader. One could argue that a good corporate leader does this anyway, but only few are actually that good.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere There is a huge difference in Gaming between being in the management team and being managed. As in a job, "being managed" is not a skill. Being the manager is a whole different beast. So indeed if someone cites "gaming experience" that's like "I was managed". Basically worthless.

Comment: That was a very bad edit. RPG, while in theory being the correct term for Role Playing Games, is in fact a different genre. RPGs are not bound to In Character actions and are effectively limited to game actions, while roleplaying would be what Kinky Auntie does with her husband late at night, both in a game and in the sack.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Experience with games may backfire. I see no advantage in mentioning it and a potential risk of not being taken seriously.

*However*, you do have experience in handling groups of people, organizing them. That's good. Just don't focus on the game aspect. Call it a club. Maybe a gaming club. And focus on what you did to make it work. Like organizing a certain amount of people to be available. Organizing what they had to bring. Recruiting new people to always keep the pool filled to what you think you needed to function optimally.

In the end, if the game gave you one reward for 40 people in the group, it's not that different from your superior giving you one raise for a single member of your team. Handling the disappointment of the 39 others is a valuable skill.

Reorganizing on the fly when two key people call in sick is a valuable skill.

Staying calm when 40 people ask for things is a valuable skill.

So focus on what you did and what you learned. Don't lie about the fact that it was a game, but don't let it stand out.

Answer (score 0):

You're not the first nor the last to leverage this type of experience. For example:

[image: clan mmo leader site:linkedin.com]

And sum your experience relative to your career. For example:

> If the only reason you want to move out of your current job is because you don't want anyone to give you orders, believe me - you are better off playing clash of clans and being the only one in your castle, rather than standing alone in real-world.

**References**

- [Linkedin Search](https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/index/?keywords=%2Bclan%20%2Bmmo%20%2Blead%20-director%20-franchise%20-art%20-designer&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER&page=2)
- [What "Clash of Clans" taught me?](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-clash-clans-taught-me-subhendu-pattnaik)

Comment: Another example of leveraging gaming experience: https://www.portent.com/blog/internet-marketing/marketing-dungeons-dragons-2011.htm